# Misunderstanding Akka become/unbecome

Tags: scala, akka

The following code:

```
class HotSwapActor extends Actor {
  import context._
  def angry: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    case "foo" => sender ! "I am already angry!"
    case "bar" => become(happy)
  }

  def happy: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    case "bar" => sender ! "I am already happy :-)"; unbecome
    case "foo" => become(angry)
  }

  def receive = {
    case "foo" => become(angry)
    case "bar" => become(happy)
  }
}

class OtherActor extends Actor {
  val system = ActorSystem()
  val actor = system.actorOf(Props[HotSwapActor])
  def receive = {
    case "start" =>
      actor ! "foo"
      actor ! "bar"
      actor ! "bar"
      actor ! "foo"
    case a @ _ => println(a)
  }
}

object HotSwapMain extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem()
  val actor = system.actorOf(Props[OtherActor])
  actor ! "start"
}
```

Has the output:

> I am already happy :-)

But souldn't it be

> I am already happy :-) I am already angry!

Or am I missing the semantic of unbecome in **unbecome** in the **bar** case of the happy PartialFunction?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is how is the flow.

1. Msg "foo" sent --> `receive` receives the message. `angry` becomes the receive function. Any next message will be sent to `angry`
2. Msg "bar" sent --> `angry` receives message. `happy` becomes the receive function. Any next message will be sent to `happy`
3. Msg "bar" sent --> `happy` receives message. It replied `I am already happy :-)` message. And then it `unbecomes`. 
   As per [api](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/#akka.actor.ActorContext) for all the previous calls to `context.become`, the `discardOld` was set as default to true. Now after replacing itself there is nothing left to become the next receiver. It takes the default one i.e. `receive` as the receiver
4. Msg "foo" sent --> `receive` receives the message. `angry` becomes the receive function. Any next message will be sent to `angry`

Comment: @Randall Couldn't agree more. I used it as a metaphor to explain it as the function which processes the message. So I had to name it something. And because it is of type `Receive` hence I used it

Comment: @RandallSchulz as you said the become/unbecome push/pop stack. however, on trying [this](https://gist.github.com/Rohitwagh/01d8fc6082aa6d5f254c#file-becomeunbecomeexample-scala) example, the unbecome directly set receive as the message handler instead of previous method.

Comment: It *replaced* the top method. The API doc states: Changes the Actor's behavior to become the new 'Receive' (PartialFunction[Any, Unit]) handler. This method acts upon the behavior stack as follows:

if discardOld = true it will replace the top element (i.e. the current behavior)
if discardOld = false it will keep the current behavior and push the given one atop
The default of replacing the current behavior has been chosen to avoid memory leaks in case client code is written without consulting this documentation first (i.e. always pushing new closures and never issuing an unbecome()).

Answer (score 3):

become takes an optional second parameter 'discardOld'. By default this is true. So that the stack will not be maintained. If you want the stack to be maintained, and get the result as - "I am already happy :-) I am already angry!", pass the argument discardOld=false to your become function.